# How to retain toggle checkbox state after submittin form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to retain a checkbox state of a form after submitting. It is the type of checkbox that you can only check one of. I have seen a question on here that goes about retaingin the state of a checkbox via PHP using `<?php if(isset($_GET['gender'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>`, but with my code:

```
<form action="example.com/example" method="GET">
    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" <?php if(isset($_GET['gender'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" <?php if(isset($_GET['gender'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
    <input type="radio" value="other" name="gender" <?php if(isset($_GET['gender'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

that line of php won't work because they will all be checked. Is there a way to retain the state of a checkbox without having to use something like:

`if(isset($_GET['gender']) && $_GET['gender'] == 'value')`

because i have a feeling this could be done in a better way.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: `I'm trying to retain a checkbox state of a form *after* submitting.` Emphasis added. So, where is the rest of your code? Specifically the code that submits the form then returns the user to the view. Without what you are coding, its whack-a-mole to help you on this one.

Comment: I don't appreciate the tone in your comment. Either way, what i said still stands, im trying to learn new things, and have just an empty `body` with that piece of code in it. I added a little bit more of the php that didn't work. What im after is that *after* submitting, i want to retain the state of the selected checkbox.

Comment: Tone? Still don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You yourself have quoted what i am trying to accomplish:
`I'm trying to retain a checkbox state of a form after submitting`

Comment: Its vague. Submitting how? If you submitted through AJAX for example all retention is a nil subject.If the `action="example.com/example"` is the same page as where it's coming from, then i suppose one has to guess this.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean now. I have never worked with ajax so this flew past my mind. It is just submitting to itself, and afterwards i use php to process them. The page reloads wich makes the checkboxes uncheck. I'm trying to make it so that a checkbox remains checked after submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you described is, in essence, exactly what you'd need. You can make it a bit shorter though if that's what you want:

```
<?php 
    $gender = $_GET['gender'] ?? false;
    function checked(){ echo 'checked'; }
?>
<form action="example.com/example" method="GET">
    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" <?php if($gender == 'male') checked(); ?>>
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" <?php if($gender == 'female') checked(); ?>>
    <input type="radio" value="other" name="gender" <?php if($gender == 'other') checked(); ?>>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The `??` operator that's used here is the `null coalescence operator`, added to `PHP` since version `7.0`. What it does is returns the part right of the operato if the part left of the operator is not set.

```
$gender = $_GET['gender'] ?? false;
```

Has the same result as:

```
if(isset($_GET['gender']))
    $gender = $_GET['gender'];
else
    $gender = false;
```

While there's functionally nothing wrong with either your code or the code I suggested above, mixing `PHP` and `HTML` is usually seen as bad practice. I'd recommend making use of a templating engine - for example, [`Smarty`](https://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I felt like my way was kind of hacky, so i wondered if there would be a better way.

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want that only one should be checked.Then your code will be like.

```
<form action="example.com/example" method="GET">
    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender">
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender">
    <input type="radio" value="other" name="gender">
</form>
```